# In HTML which way round should <a/> and <h1/> be nested?

Tags: html, xhtml

Is there a more correct order for nesting a `<a>` and `<h1>` elements in HTML?

e.g.:

```
<a href="www.example.com"><h1>Example!</h1></a>
```

or

```
<h1><a href="www.example.com">Example!</a></h1>
```

Comment: In general inline element such as anchor tag should not contain block level element, apart of being invalid prior to HTML5 it just doesn't "feel" right in my opinion at least.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.1 and older:

- An `h1` may contain an `a`
- An `a` may *not* contain an `h1`

So `<h1><a>…</a></h1>`

In the HTML 5 draft:

- An `h1` may contain an `a`
- An `a` may contain an `h1` (but only if the `a` is somewhere an `h1` is allowed — see the comments on this answer)

So either, but browser support may vary (such is life on the bleeding edge).

Comment: (HTML5) *"An `a` may contain an `h1`"* **If** the `a` is within an element that can contain an `h1` (because the content model of `a` is transparent; it inherits its parent's content model: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#transparent)

Comment: @T.J. I think this point is vital to a correct answer. @David does it seem correct to you?

Comment: @Alison: I suppose it's an important point; I was just augmenting David's already excellent answer. Basically, you can't put an `h1` inside an `a` inside a `span` (`span > a > h1`), because `span` can't contain `h1`. But for instance, you can put an `h1` inside an `a` inside `body` (`body > a > h1`) or `div` (`div > a > h1`), which I suspect is where most people would want to.

Answer (score 3):

this is the right answer:

```
<h1><a href="www.example.com">Example!</a></h1>
```

Comment: @Alison no problem, thanks you for the comment, then close the question with the correct answer please :)

Comment: Think I have to choose David's now - it's a bit more complete

Answer (score 2):

HTML4, XHTML

```
<h1><a href="">Text</a></h1>
```

HTML5

```
<h1><a href="">Text</a></h1>
<a href=""><h1>Text</h1></a>
```

It's acceptable in HTML5 as the anchor tag's been made 'block level'.

Some good info on block level and inline level tags can be found at http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Comment: seems to be some disagreement with @David Dorward / @T.J. Crowder on the status of an anchor tag.

Comment: @Alison: I wouldn't say there's *disagreement*. :-) @Scott: `a` is not a block-level element.

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase. You can wrap block level elements in `a` in HTML5 whereas you can't in HTML4

Comment: Heh I think I understand, but now I'm getting more confused