# In HTML, should block level elements always wrap <a> tags?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

In HTML, should block level elements always wrap `<a>` tags? What if it's necessary for the  tag to wrap the block level element to ensure the correct styles are applied? For example can this

```
<h3><a href="/">Your Header</a></h3>
```

be this

```
<a href="/"><h3>Your Header</h3></a>
```

NB: I'm going for the latter approach to ensure the correct styles are applied (I'm working with legacy code that is just not worth re-working for this one element), but while doing this I was interested to know what the community's views are.

And yes I have read this question [In HTML which way round should a and h1 be nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080261/in-html-which-way-round-should-a-and-h1-be-nested) but I'm not sure if a different or more flexible rule applies for `<h3>` tags.

Taking in the comments below and looking again at the code, I have two possible solutions:

1. Wrap the `<h3>` elements with `<a>` elements (ok in HTML5)
2. Add `.class a` to the CSS so that it inherits parent `div` styles as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="class">
    <h3><a href="/">Your Header</a></h3>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.class, .class a {
    width:296px;
    height:46px;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#FE5815;
}
```

Comment: The answer in the thread you posted about is the correct answer. It would apply to any header element, and probably to any block level element as well.

Comment: `"but I'm not sure if a different or more flexible rule applies for h3 tags"` Why would you think that there would be a big difference between h1 and h3 tags? They are very similar.

Comment: Basically, don't use the bottom case, unless you care about supporting HTML5-compatible browsers only.

Comment: @Simon André Forsburg - They are similar but not identical. I'm also more interested in views on wrapping the h3 element with an a element to enable the correct CSS to be applied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In HTML which way round should <a/> and <h1/> be nested?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080261/in-html-which-way-round-should-a-and-h1-be-nested)

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate. There is no reason to expect that `h3` would be different from `h1` (or other block elements) in this respect; this becomes obvious if you check out the old answers and their references.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela - this question isn't just about 'a' vs 'h3' tags but also about using this to ensure the correct styles are applied when dealing with legacy code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context, it is absolutely allowed for the `a` element to contain the `h3` element, at least according to HTML5.

An `a` element is known as a "transparent" element: it may contain whatever its parent element may contain. The only criterion is that it may not contain any other "interactive" content, e.g. other `a` elements, `button` elements, `iframe` elements. In this case, presuming that the first version is allowed, the second version is also allowed under HTML5.

[This is the page in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) that specifies this. It takes a little interpretation to understand, unfortunately...

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#transparent_xref2 ... I learned something today!

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is one case in HTML5 where

```
<h3><a href="/">Your Header</a></h3>
```

would be valid, but

```
<a href="/"><h3>Your Header</h3></a>
```

would not, and that's when the parent of the `<h3>` element is an `<hgroup>` element.

The `<hgroup>` element can only have `<h?>` children, so while the transparent content model of the `<a>` element allows an `<h3>` to be its child, the `<a>` element remains invalid as a child of `<hgroup>`.

In this case

```
<hgroup>
  <h3>
    <a href="/">Your Header</a>
  </h3>
</hgroup>
```

and

```
<a href="/">
  <hgroup>
    <h3>Your Header</h3>
  </hgroup>
</a>
```

are the only valid arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

Both are ok

```
<h3><a href="/">Your Header</a></h3>


<a href="/"><h3>Your Header</h3></a>
```

But I will use 1st one if I don't care whatever there is in the anchor and I just want it to look like `<h3>`

And I will use 2nd one if I am concerned about a particular part of anchor needs `<h3>`. For

example below I need the 2nd one.

```
<a href="/"> check normal text <h3>check large text</h3></a>
```

Comment: That's a terrible example of the use of an h3 element. You should not use heading elements just to get a styling effect.

Comment: I know, just an example of scenario. More appropriate example is
<a href="/"> Hi <b>Alohci</b></a>

Answer (score 1):

In HTML 4.01 and XHTML, an `h3` tag may contain a `a` tag, but not the other way around.

In HTML5, both ways are valid.  If an `a` tag contains an `h3` tag though, the `a` tag must NOT be nested in an element that cannot contain an `h3` element.